# Modal dynamic fields undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am working on laravel project, I have a modal form and user can add new fields which I added dynamically using jquery and it works well, but the problem is when I send the form values to the controller the values of the newly dynamic fields is not send or like they lost when the modal is closed after submit, any help?

this is the modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="{{$task->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-login modal-lg" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="card card-signup card-plain">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                         <h5 class="modal-title card-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Task</h5>
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                         </button>

                                     
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                         <form  >
                          <div class="form-row">
                               <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="issue" 
                                         value="{{$task->issue}}">
                               </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-row pt-2">
                              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                   <select name="tag" id="tag" class="form-control" >
                                   <option value="{{$task->tag}}" selected>{{$task->tag}}</option>
                                                      @if($task->tag=='CM')
                                                       <option value="PM">PM</option>
                                                      @else
                                                        <option value="CM">CM</option>
                                                      @endif

                                    </select>
                             </div>

                          </div>

                                <div class="form-row pt-2">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <textarea class="form-control"  name="root_cause" 
                                          placeholder="Root Cause"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row pt-2">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 form-group" id="container{{$task->id}}">
                                          <select class="form-control" name="add_used_part[]" >
                                          <option disabled selected>used spare parts</option>
                                              @foreach($task->machine->part as $part)
                                          <option value="{{$part->id}}"> {{$part->part_name}} 
                                          </option>
                                              @endforeach
                                          </select>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="form-group col-md-4" id="container2{{$task->id}}">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control "  id="quantity" 
                                         name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity">
                                   </div>

                <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addField( '{{$task->machine->part}}','{{$task->id}}' ) ">Add another spare part</a>
                                   </div>

                                           
                                   <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                                    <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
                                     onclick="submitajax('{{$task->id}}') ; return 
                                      false;">Submit</button>
                                   </div>
                          </form>            

                      </div>
                               
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

this jquery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addField(a,b){
  
       var parts = JSON.parse(a);
       
        // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
        var container1 = document.getElementById("container"+b);
        var container2 = document.getElementById("container2"+b);
        


        //Create and append select list

        var selectList = document.createElement("select");
        selectList.name="add_used_part[]";
        container1.append(selectList);


        //Create and append the options
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option"); 
            option.value = parts[i].id;
            option.text = parts[i].part_name;
            selectList.append(option);
        }

  var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.name = "q";
            container2.append(input);
    }





function submitajax(id){

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});


    
    var tag = $("#tag").val();
    var add_used_part= $("[name='add_used_part[]']").val();
    var quantity= $("[name='quantity[]']").val();
  
    /* this alert only one value of the add_used_part and quantity arrays 
    alert (id+tag+' '+add_used_part+' '+quantity);

    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:"{{ route('task.update',['id' => $task->id ] ) }}",
       data:{tag:tag, add_used_part:add_used_part, quantity:quantity},
       success:function(data){
          alert(data.success);
       }
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this fragment:

```
var add_used_part= $("[name='add_used_part[]']").val();
var quantity= $("[name='quantity[]']").val();
```

You can't read many values this way, maybe you can try something like this:

```
var add_used_part= [];
$.each( $("[name='add_used_part[]']"), function(){
   add_used_part.push( $(this).val() )
})
var quantity= [];
$.each( $("[name='quantity[]']"), function(){
   quantity.push( $(this).val() )
})
```

And then send these arrays via AJAX request.

P.S: Sorry, I saw the question date just now :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply i will try your idea and see what will happen